# How to connect to a Https that has a self signed certificate using wget?

Tags: ssl, https, openssl, wget, redhat

Using redhat, I've tried to connect to a https server using wget,and exported the https_proxy but it keeps telling me that:

> Self-signed certificate encountered. Proxy request sent, awaiting
>   response... 403 Forbidden

It connects, finds the certificate but the connection doesn't happens.
I've tried with --no-certificate as well and got the same answers.

I tried as well to get their certificate via openssl but I am not sure if am I giving the right command.

Comment: Who has the self-signed certificate?  The server? The client?  Both?

Comment: The Client certificate was missing. I'll post a complete answer next week. thanks ice13berg

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.